# ASP.NET/JAVASCRIPT disabling dropdown list from RadioButton value (client side)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Currently I have three RadioButtons:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbShowAll" runat="server" CssClass="radio-inline" GroupName="grpReadStatus" onchange="disableDDL()"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbIssuedTo" runat="server" CssClass="radio-inline" GroupName="grpReadStatus" onchange="disableDDL()"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbReceivedFrom" runat="server" CssClass="radio-inline" GroupName="grpReadStatus" onchange="disableDDL()"/>
```

And two DropDownLists:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBuyer" runat="server" class="form-control" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSeller" runat="server" class="form-control" />
```

How can I, without touching server side, disable the dropdownList according to which RadioButton is selected in Javascript function?

I have tried:

```
function disableDDL() {
    if (document.getElementById("rbShowAll").checked) {
        document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
    }
    else if (documne.getElementById("rbIssuedTo").checked) {
        document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("rbReceivedFrom").checked) {
        document.getElementById("ddlButer").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Can someone please advise on this? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working code snippet for you, There were plenty of typos and that's why it wasn't working, I have corrected them all :) have a look.

```js
function disableDDL() {
  document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = false;
  if (document.getElementById("rbShowAll").checked) {
    //alert('rbShowAll');
    document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById("rbIssuedTo").checked) {
    //alert('rbIssuedTo');
    document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById("rbReceivedFrom").checked) {
    //alert('rbReceivedFrom');
    document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = true;
  } //else {
  //alert('Else');
  //}
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="rbShowAll" class="radio-inline" name="grpReadStatus" onchange="javascript:disableDDL()">Show all
<input type="radio" id="rbIssuedTo" class="radio-inline" name="grpReadStatus" onchange="javascript:disableDDL()">Issued to
<input type="radio" id="rbReceivedFrom" class="radio-inline" name="grpReadStatus" onchange="javascript:disableDDL()">Recieved from

<select id="ddlBuyer">
  <option>Select Buyer</option>
  <option>Buyer 1</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlSeller">
  <option>Select Seller</option>
  <option>Seller 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

asp:RadioButton is rendered as a **span** element with the **radio** inside so the event onchage you put will be assigned to the span element and won't work.
Instead use directly:

```html
<input type="radio" 
       id="rbShowAll" runat="server"
       name="grpReadStatus" 
       class="radio-inline" 
       onchange="disableDDL()" />
```

Test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/pacmhjjL/2/

```js
function disableDDL() {
    if (document.getElementById("rbShowAll").checked) {
        document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("rbIssuedTo").checked) {
        document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("rbReceivedFrom").checked) {
        document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" 
       id="rbShowAll"  
       class="radio-inline" 
       name="grpReadStatus" onchange="disableDDL()" />

<input type="radio" 
       id="rbIssuedTo"  
       class="radio-inline" 
       name="grpReadStatus" onchange="disableDDL()" />

<input type="radio" 
       id="rbReceivedFrom"  
       class="radio-inline" 
       name="grpReadStatus" onchange="disableDDL()" />

<select id="ddlBuyer" class="form-control">
    <option>ddlBuyer</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlSeller" class="form-control">
    <option>ddlSeller</option>
</select>
```

I've corrected your js functin since it contains typos.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your html accordingly..

```
<input type="radio" id="rbShowAll" class="radio-inline" name="grpReadStatus" onchange="javascript:disableDDL()">Show all
<input type="radio" id="rbIssuedTo" class="radio-inline" name="grpReadStatus" onchange="javascript:disableDDL()">Issued to
<input type="radio" id="rbReceivedFrom" class="radio-inline" name="grpReadStatus" onchange="javascript:disableDDL()">Recieved from

<select id="ddlBuyer">
  <option>Select Buyer</option>
  <option>Buyer 1</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlSeller">
  <option>Select Seller</option>
  <option>Seller 1</option>
</select>
```

Modify your javascript function accordingly..

```
    function disableDDL() {
        if (document.getElementById("rbShowAll").checked) {
            document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("rbIssuedTo").checked) {
            document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = false;
     }
else if (document.getElementById("rbReceivedFrom").checked) {
            document.getElementById("ddlSeller").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("ddlBuyer").disabled = true;
}
```